# How to find entries in a Column - where an adjacent column switches value, and then reverts back to the original value?

Tags: sql, mysql

I work in a Hat-Making Factory.

One of the Machines that we process that Hats on is called the Spinner.
We manufacture the Hats in Batches of 10,000 Hats at a time.
Each Batch is identified by a number which always begins with 1000- and is then followed by six natural numbers. (So for example, 1000495867, 1000333485 etc.)

The information for each Batch’s manufacture on the Spinning machine is feed into a MySQL relational database. Specifically, into a table called RS_SPINNER_MACHINESTATUS. The way this table works, is that it takes a recording at every minute (always at :00 seconds of each minute). So, in a Day you’ll have 1440 Rows or Entries – as that is the number of Minutes in a Day.

The machine is not always running non-stop. In fact, there’s some days where it is not running at all – but it will keep recording Rows into the Table mentioned previously. (We don’t need to get into it – but it just records these rows with information along the lines of ‘No Batch Active’).

The table looks like this:

| BATCH | BATCH_ACTIVE | RUN_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 0 | 01-SEP-2023 13:04 |
| 1000495867 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:05 |
| 1000495867 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:06 |
| 1000495867 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:07 |
| 1000495867 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:08 |
| null | 0 | 01-SEP-2023 13:09 |
| 1000333485 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:10 |
| 1000333485 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:11 |
| null | 0 | 01-SEP-2023 13:12 |

The Column BATCH_ACTIVE is binary – it can only be either 0 or 1.

0 means that no Batch is currently running on the Machine (it is sitting idle).

1 means that a Batch is running on the Machine.

And based on this you can infer the Start & End time of a Batch by subtracting its Min. from its Max. Timestamp where BATCH_ACTIVE = 1.

From my experience of the table so far, once a Batch starts running on the machine, the BATCH_ACTIVE Column switches from 0 to 1 – and it stays at 1, until the Batch is finished – at which point it reverts to 0 again.

However – this is what I’d like to check with SQL!

**Is it possible to write an SQL query – to check if the BATCH_ACTIVE Column switches from 1 to 0 – and then back to 1 – within a Batch?**

For example – could the Query detect something like this:

| BATCH | BATCH_ACTIVE | RUN_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 0 | 01-SEP-2023 13:04 |
| 1000495211 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:05 |
| 1000495211 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:06 |
| 1000495211 | 0 | 01-SEP-2023 13:07 |
| 1000495211 | 1 | 01-SEP-2023 13:08 |
| null | 0 | 01-SEP-2023 13:09 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to phrase it as a gaps and islands problem.  A matching batch is one which has more than one island of 1s.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BATCH ORDER BY RUN_TIMESTAMP) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BATCH, BATCH_ACTIVE
                                 ORDER BY RUN_TIMESTAMP) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT BATCH
FROM cte
WHERE BATCH_ACTIVE = 1
GROUP BY BATCH
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rn1 - rn2) > 1;
```

The above approach uses the difference in row numbers method.  The difference `rn1 - rn2` will be unique to each island of 1s.  A matching batch, then, is one which has more than one difference in row numbers value.

Comment: Thank You!

May I ask how does the last line work:
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT rn1 - rn2) > 1

Comment: I have already explained this in my answer.  I suggest running `SELECT * FROM cte` to see how it is working.